# Finding .npm debug logs in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: docker, azure, dev, npm

I have an existing build pipeline for a Vue web app that has worked flawlessly for over a year now up until today. I'm not a devops guy so I don't understand it 100% and got thrown into this, but here is the background of it.

It's a CI process built on Docker with the build process controlled with Azure DevOps and pushed to Google Cloud and Kubernetes (that's a short version of it all). The Docker build command runs a docker file in the project where it is failing that looks like this:

```
FROM node

COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.13-alpine

COPY ./config/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./config/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY --from=0 /project/dist/ /app

CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Everything runs perfectly until it gets to the npm install, when it breaks and kicks out these lines:

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:‌
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-06-26T21_20_37_033Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1‌

### [error]The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

### [error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

### [section]Finishing: Build an image.

I could probably dig a bit more, but I have no idea where the root/.npm/_logs file for the npm debug logs are in an Azure build process. I've searched everywhere. Also, as mentioned, this build process worked perfectly on a deploy as of two days ago and nothing was modified in the build pipeline.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also trying to get the log files from 'root/.npm/_logs', but I can't able to find this location. Have you found that path where it was located?